# Why firebase authUI can't use google account login now, but can login before

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-authentication, google-authentication, firebaseui

Why firebase authUI can't use google account login now, but can login before?
Use "Sign in with email" can login but use "Sign in with Google" failed now.
Both sign in function were normal before.

Logcat error message:

> E/AuthUI: A sign-in error occurred.
> com.firebase.ui.auth.FirebaseUiException: Code: 10, message: 10:

Comment: Please provide some more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had solved this Problem.

Solution:
1.Double click signingReport->get the SHA-1 .
2.Copy this generated SHA-1 from Android Studio,then paste to Firebase ->Project Setting->
General Setting->SHA FingerPrint.

Can login with google account.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Solution**

If you are using Google Developer Console, follow the ensuing steps.

**Step 1:**

1. Sign in to Google Play Console
2. Click the App name
3. On the Left Column >> Click Setup >> Click App Integrity (see Figure 1) >> Click App Signing >> Click the Copy Icon

[image: Figure 1.]

**Step 2:**

1- Sign in to Firebase

2- On the Left Column >> Click the Gear Icon beside the Project Overview >> Click Project Settings >> Click General (see Figure 2) >> Add Fingerprint >> Paste the Copied SHA-1 Fingerprint

[image: Figure 2.]